# Why do some individuals enjoy watching scary videos?

Tags: emotion, psychology, behavior, well-being

- Does watching scary videos affect mental health?
- Are some individuals more/less prone to feeling scared than others?

Answer (score -2):

Below are some reasons why some people enjoy and what happens when watching a scary movie:

> Horror entertainment can trigger the fight-or-flight response, which comes with a boost in adrenaline, endorphins, and dopamine. The brain can then process surroundings and conclude that the experience is not a genuine threat.

Below are some causes and effects of watching a scary movie:

> Excitation transfer: This theory states that people who experience an emotional response to horror also experience more enjoyment when threats are resolved.

> Individual empathy: People who are less empathetic enjoy horror films more, according to Professor Ron Tamborini. He suggests that “viewers with high levels of empathy should dislike horror films because they react negatively to the suffering of others.”

> Sensation-seeking: People who watch horror movies may want to stimulate sensory reactions. Studies indicate these viewers may be more aggressive than other people.

**Source of Reference** - [Concordia University](https://b.online.csp.edu/resources/article/pyschology-of-fear/)